# Make GameScene a delegate of ViewController

Tags: swift, delegates

I am trying to pass some data from my ViewController to a gamescene and call a method on that scene using the delegate pattern. In my view controller I set a launchDelegate and set a variable:

```
weak var launchDelegate: LaunchDelegate?
```

Then when the user presses the launch button it triggers a function where I check the delegate and call the method with the data I need to pass.

```
if let delegate = launchDelegate
    {
        delegate.launch(angle: Int(angleSlider.value), velocity: Int(velocitySlider.value))
    }
```

In my game scene I adhere to the protocol and set the viewcontroller's delegate to self (GameScene).

```
var viewController: GameViewController?

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
{
    backgroundColor = UIColor(hue: 0.669, saturation: 0.99, brightness: 0.67, alpha: 1)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    viewController?.launchDelegate = self
}
```

Now when ever the user presses the launch button nothing happens. It just hangs and the delegates are nil? Anyone have an idea why the delegate is not being set?

Comment: Are you setting `viewController`'s value when you create the GameScene?

Comment: not 100% sure. I am doing this to create the game scene in the viewcontroller. if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene"). Then I am presenting it with skview.presentScene(scene)

Comment: The point that @paulvs is making is that in the code you have shown `viewController` might be nil. How and when do you set this to anything?

Comment: ah, you know what I never do. somewhere in there I need viewController = GameViewController().

Comment: Thanks you guys you made me realize something. Inside of Viewcontroller I set launchDelegate = scene and it worked out thank you!